# How to flag a group of columns based on data in a second column?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to figure out, for each duplicate group in column A, if that group has data in column b. If so, mark column c as a 1 for that group of duplicates. How can I do this please?

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE #t10
(
    docid VARCHAR (20)  NULL
    , leaveDate DATE    NULL
)

INSERT INTO #t10(
    docid
  , leaveDate
)
VALUES
    ('abcde123' , '20230101')
   ,('abcde123' , null)
   ,('defg123' , null)
   ,('defg123' , null)
   ,('hijk123' , null)
   ,('hijk123' , null)

SELECT docid
     , leaveDate
     
FROM #t10
```

Desired Results:

[image]

Comment: Consider a windowed `COUNT` inside a `CASE` expression.

Comment: Thanks @Larnu, I gave this a go, but it returns all 1's.  CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT docid , COUNT(*) AS dupes  FROM #t1 WHERE leaveDate IS NOT NULL GROUP BY docid HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS col

Comment: That isn't a windowed `COUNT`; that's a subquery. It's also not correlated, so it's not surprising it always returns `1`; provided at least *one* row with a non-`NULL` value in the table exists, then the `EXISTS` will return TRUE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, a windowed `COUNT` and a `CASE` expression is likely all you need here:

```sql
CASE COUNT(LeaveDate) OVER (PARTITION BY DocID) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

Comment: Thank you @Larnu.  I didn't know what a windowed Count was.  I learned something important from you.  This has opened my eyes to a number of possibilities on how to use a CASE statement with aggregate functions.  I am grateful for your time in helping me and others.  Thank you for your help.